# Do I need Facebook's approval of my website to have "Login with Facebook" feature?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm looking to build a site and was considering a "login with facebook" feature, so that users would not be anonymous. I don't need autoposting to facebook or anything like that, but would like to use facebook profile pictures and names. Does anyone know if this falls under the category of "Facebook Open Graph", and thus needs facebook's approval of my own site? Or can any website use "login with facebook"?

Comment: No, you do not need any extra approval. Just follow the guidelines laid out in the developer section, and have an eye on Platform Policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every website can use the "login with Facebook" - which is called "Facebook Connect". Open Graph is a different thing, although you could use Open Graph functionality when using Facebook Connect.

Please have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/01/25/clarifying-our-platform-policies/, where Facebook clarified the use of Facebook connect.